# Auto-vectorization of scalar product in loop

Tags: c++, openmp, intel, auto-vectorization

I am trying to autovectorize the following loop. In the following we loop with the `i-` and `j-`loop over the lower triangle of a matrix. Unfortunetly the vectorization report cannot vectorize (=translate to AVX SIMD instructions) the j- and the k-loop. But I think it is straightforward, because there are no pointer aliases (`#pragma ivdep` and compiler option `-D NOALIAS`) and the data (x: 1D-array and p: 1D-array) is aligned to 64 bytes.

It could be, that the `if`-statement is a problem, but even with the `if`-free solution (expensive shifting operation and count the sign of a double) the compiler is not able to vectorize this loop.

```
__assume_aligned(x, 64);
__assume_aligned(p, 64);
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:accum)
for ( int i = 1 ; i < N ; i++ ){ // loop over lower triangle (i,j), OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++ ){ // <-- remark #25460: No loop optimizations reported
        double __attribute__((aligned(64))) scalarp = 0.0;
        #pragma omp simd
        for ( int k=0 ; k < D ; k++ ){ // <-- remark #25460: No loop optimizations reported
            // scalar product of \sum_k x_{i,k} \cdot x_{j,k}
            scalarp += x[i*D + k] * x[j*D + k];
        }

        // Alternative to following if:
        // accum +=  - ( (long long) floor( - ( scalarp + p[i] + p[j] ) ) >> 63);
        #pragma ivdep
        if ( scalarp + p[i] + p[j] >= 0 ){ // check if condition is satisfied
            accum += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Does it refer to the problem, that OpenMP starting points for each OpenMP thread are not known until run-time? I thought it this resolves the `simd` clause and Intels auto-vectorization is aware of that.

Intel Compiler: 18.0.2 20180210

edit: I've looked into the assembly and now it is clear that the code is already vectorized, sorry for boardering all of you.

Comment: What does the asm look like?  Doesn't the `OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED` for the outer loop mean something was vectorized with SIMD?

Comment: What do you mean with _vectorize_? Do you want the compiler to use SIMD instructions? If that is the case, then I don't think it is possible with your current algorithm, because you are accessing your data in a non-sequential order. (You are jumping in memory as soon as you increment `I` or `j`.)

Comment: Vectorizing the inner loop over `k` should be no problem for your compiler I think. Did you look at the assembly?

Comment: When you throw omp simd on a reduction loop without declaring the reduction, you are asking for trouble; certainly there is no point in asking us what will happen.   Perhaps the loop has been discarded as dead code.  We might wish for an option to point out dead code elimination in an opt-report.

Comment: @tim18: Dead code means, that I should not get the correct result, but I get the correct result, so the loop does not get discarded.

Comment: Dead code means the compiler determines it may be skipped without changing results.  In this case you are likely correct, the code is optimized by loop nest interchange so the original inner loop is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the assembly really helps. Code is already vectorized. `OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED` takes also care of inner loop in this particular case.